# android: OnEditorActionListener stops the app

Tags: android

Please when I try to run this app it stops.

The problem is with OnEditorActionListener, if i delete the app loads and runs ok.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IMEDemo2 extends Activity  
{       EditText et;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            et.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() { 
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) { 
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                    return true; 
                } 
            });             
    }
```

}

Comment: Please post the LogCat errors. Also you have an errant curly brace (`}`) in your `onEditorAction()` method, I don't see how it could compile like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't initializing your `et` field so when you try to set the listener, you will get a `NullPointerException`.

To initialize `et`, put...

```
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
```

...before the line `et.setOnEditorActionListener(...)`.

Change `R.id.myEditText`  in my example to whatever the resource id is in your `main.xml` file.

Comment: @pietmau : Click the check symbol to the left of my answer in order to accept it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to to define the edit text further by using 
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.I'd.EDITTEXT)
The all caps is whatever you set the I'd as in your XML file